# Adding Image to Rich Text Editor

Tags: content-editor, content-management

While adding images to `Rich Text Editor's` body field, they are getting added but not in the desired position. All images are getting added to the Top of RTE.

**For example:** I need to add an image in line 10 and I placed the cursor at line 10, clicked on "***Insert Sitecore Media***" and selected the image from `media library`. I see that the image is added to Line 1 of the `RTE` body and not in Line 10. I need to again move those images to that position. How to fix this?

Comment: I could not replicate this issue on Sitecore 10 or 9.0.2. What version are you using? Have you tried different browser and clearing Sitecore and browser cache? Any errors in browser console?

Comment: @Kamil I am using 9.3.0 and this is same across all browsers. I see couple of errors in browser console. Let me fix them and get back to you. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We triaged to a Sitecore bug and they have a work around for this. Hope this helps.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001423